# How to insert int into @Value annotation from .yml properties?

Tags: spring

Hey guys I am trying to insert a configurable variable from my properties file into the @Transactional method, which is accepting an integer.

This what I did seems like this:

[image]

I would like to insert a configurable @Value = ("${TIMEOUT_TIMER}") from the properties instead of this final class variable.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Create the class variable

```
@Value("${TIMEOUT_TIMER}")
private Integer timeOutTimer;
```

And then just use that variable in the *@Transactional* annotation like you're doing right now.

It would look like

```
public class Test {
    @Value("${TIMEOUT_TIMER}")
    private Integer timeOutTimer;

    @Transactional(timeout = timeOutTimer)
    public void yourMethod() { 
         
    }

}
```

Comment: This is not possible!
Timeout value must be constant and cannot be given from class variable or constructor.
It can only via static variable, which I don't know if it is very good for use in microservices...